# Trying to get property of non-object in Laravel 5.5 while getting object from array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am new to Laravel and trying to get an object from an array. However I am receiving the following issue:

> Trying to get property of non-object in Laravel 5.5 while getting object from array

Bellow code in Blade Template:

```
@foreach($writers as $writer)
    <?php
        $order_writer = DB::table('tbl_writers_payment')
                        ->select('fk_writer_id')
                        ->orderBy('pk_payment_id', 'desc')
                        ->where('fk_order_id',$row->pk_order_id)
    ?>

    @if($writer->pk_writer_id == $order_writer->fk_writer_id)
        <option selected value="{{ $writer->pk_writer_id }}">
            {{ $writer->name }}
        </option>
    @endif

@endforeach
```

In the above code, when I compare the `[$order_writer->fk_writer_id]` code in the `if` statement so that will return me that `object not found`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, `WHERE` should come before `ORDER BY` ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)). Try doing this:

```
$order_writer = DB::table('tbl_writers_payment')
                ->select('fk_writer_id')
                ->where('fk_order_id',$row->pk_order_id)
                ->orderBy('pk_payment_id', 'desc')
```

Also, after that, try using `->get()`:

```
$order_writer = DB::table('tbl_writers_payment')
                ->select('fk_writer_id')
                ->where('fk_order_id',$row->pk_order_id)
                ->orderBy('pk_payment_id', 'desc')
                ->get();
```

If the above doesn't work for you, you might consider using [Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#conditional-clauses).

Comment: must be `->first()` not `->get()`

Comment: Thanks @Praveen Kumar Purushothaman i try both options but still not working.

Comment: @HazratBilal Try `->first()`?

Comment: @Davit Thanks... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

If multiple payments available

```
$order_writers = DB::table('tbl_writers_payment')
                        ->select('fk_writer_id')
                        ->where('fk_order_id',$row->pk_order_id)
                        ->orderBy('pk_payment_id', 'desc')
                        ->get();

    @foreach($order_writers as $order_writer)
        @if($writer->pk_writer_id == $order_writer->fk_writer_id)
            <option selected value="{{ $writer->pk_writer_id }}">
                {{ $writer->name }}
            </option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
```